# Getting Identity From Insert Into/ Select

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, output, insert-into, scope-identity

I am working on a script in SQL Server 2012 (as backend to a Classic ASP page) to select all rows from my initial table (`aaa_test_ap`) and distribute them amongst my 3 other tables (`aaa_test_users`, `aaa_test_users_positions`, and `aaa_test_users_education`).

I would like to get the identity of `aaa_test_users.ID`, once a row has been inserted into it, for use in the other two table inserts, as their FK (`User_ID`), within the same query.

Is it possible to get the identity with the `INSERT INTO` method, within one query?

I've tried using `SCOPE_Identity()`, but it only returns the last value.

With the `OUTPUT` method, how would I utilize the table values it generates, so that the values generated by the first insert statement are inserted into the next two statements, each in the correct inserted row?

First, the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[aaa_test_sp]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [first_name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [last_name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [position] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [phone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [education] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ListID] [int] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_aaa_test_sp] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[aaa_test_users]
(
    [UserID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [first_name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [last_name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_aaa_test_users] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[aaa_test_users_positions]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NULL,
    [position] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [phone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_aaa_test_users_positions] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[aaa_test_users_education] 
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NULL,
    [education] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_aaa_test_users_education] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This is the query I've been working on:

```
--declare @NewUserID nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @InsertOutput1 table (UserID nvarchar(50));

--insert, first, rows from sp to users, and get the autoNumber'ed ID,
--"NewUserID"
INSERT INTO aaa_test_users (UserName, first_name, last_name)
OUTPUT inserted.UserID INTO @InsertOutput1
    SELECT 
        UserName, first_name, last_name
    FROM aaa_test_sp
    WHERE (ListId = '1')

--select * from @InsertOutput1
--SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() As NewUserID
--set @NewUserID=(SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() )

--now that the "NewUserID" has been generated,
--insert it, along with other columns,
--into the 'users_positions' table.
--print 'new user id is ' + @NewUserID
INSERT INTO aaa_test_users_positions (UserID, position, phone)
    (SELECT 
         @NewUserID, position, phone
     FROM aaa_test_sp
     WHERE (ListId = '1')
    )

--now that the "NewUserID" has been generated,
--insert it, along with other columns,
--into the 'users_education' table 
--print @NewUserID
INSERT INTO aaa_test_users_education (UserID, education)
   (SELECT @NewUserID, education
    FROM aaa_test_sp
    WHERE (ListId = '1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You join to the table where the new ids are.

As an example for the second insert:

```
INSERT INTO aaa_test_users_positions(UserID, position, phone)
    SELECT io.UserID, position, phone
    FROM aaa_test_sp cross join
         @InsertOutput1 io
    WHERE ListId = '1';
```

Note:  given your structure, there is probably only one row in `@InsertOutput1`, so this should not produce more rows than expected.

Comment: Would the `CROSS JOIN` produce Cartesian product?  What advantages would the `CROSS JOIN` have over `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: @buck1112 . . . That appears to be the intention of your queries.  But, your insert probably only generates one `id`, so the Cartesian product will not get out of hand.

Comment: Update: I've applied this to my larger test tables, and now I get what appears to be a Cartesian product: the first table (which generates the output id's) has 1768 rows affected, while the other tables each have 3125824 (1768 squared) rows affected.  These are still all inserts, with no data existing in the tables prior to insertion.  What would be a good step to investigate the cause of this undesirable result?  Thanks